# Pass value to PHP file using JavaScript and receive new set of values from PHP to JavaScript and display in Browser

Tags: php, javascript

1. I have a page called test.html. This HTML page will contain 2 JavaScripts file. I need to pass a variable value to a PHP file using the first JavaScript file. The user can copy this javascript on as many pages as he wants for displaying output.
2. The PHP file that receives the variable from the JavaScript file retrieves some data from database depending upon the variable's value. This retrieved value can contain HTML content. This PHP file will always reside on my server.
3. All of the retrieved content (from the PHP file) needs to be passed to the second JavaScript file so that the data can be displayed in browser. This JS file will need to stay together with the first JS file in order for the data to be displayed.

***So I have this:***

**JavaScript File**

```
<script type= "text/javascript" src="http://www.myserver.com/custom_script.php?unique_id=12"></script>
```

**PHP FILE**

```
//custom_script.php
<?php
$unique_id= (int)$_GET['unique_id'];

$res = db_res(" SELECT col1, col2, col3, .... col10 FROM table WHERE unique_id = $unique_id
         LIMIT 1 "); 
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
<div id="1"><?php echo $rows['col1']; ?></div>
<div id="2"><?php echo $rows['col2']; ?></div>
<div id="3"><?php echo $rows['col3']; ?></div>
.
.
.
<div id="10"><?php echo $rows['col10']; ?></div>
```

I need to send all the HTML above from the PHP file to the second JavaScript file so that the output can be displayed. Please note that the CSS styling is also applied using Div ID, so I am expecting those styles would show up too. Please note that there may be more than 10 columns, so an efficient way of passing data is highly appreciated.

So what would be the easiest and the best way to send all the HTML data from the PHP file in one go to the 2nd javascript file residing in test.html page, so that the HTML data can be displayed in test.html file?

**EDIT 1:**

I apologize to everyone if my question has been confusing. I just thought of an example and hence wanted to add it my edit. I hope you are all aware of what Google Analytics (GA)(or any other Website Visits Stats Tracker) does. Right? You register for a Analytics account and Google gives you a piece of JS code that you copy and paste in your website. And after couple of days, you can login into your GA account to see the stats. Correct? What I am trying to do here is just the same.

Users come to MY WEBSITE and register for an account and I give them JS files that they can paste in their website. The only difference between GA and my website is that GA is personal to you and no one else, but you, the account holder can see it. Whereas in my case, your data can BE SEEN by others as well, as long as you include the JS file on your website. Because users can't just take my PHP file and run it on their server, I am trying to access MY PHP file by giving the full path to it in the JS file.

**For example:**

`<script type= "text/javascript" src="http://www.myserver.com/custom_script.php?unique_id=12"></script>`

This is not an actual JS file, rather it is just a medium for my custom_script.php script to receive the unique_id of the user, query MY database and send back the HTML data related to this requesting user. And I am stuck with this part. Hope this clairifies what I am trying to do.

Comment: +1 because you showed actual effort in what you're looking for. Anyway, your answer is AJAX paired with json encoding and decoding.

Comment: Your php file prints HTML not JS. You are requesting it as a JS file so the browser will expect JavaScript, not HTML. You should have a look at AJAX, as this is exactly what you need here. You can use jQuery library, which will make using AJAX very simple.

Comment: @STTLCU Thanks to both of you for your responses. The issue is that both the JS files will be distributed to different users. Users can simply paste those 2 JS files in their own HTML pages and change the unique_id as they see fit and the related data from Database will be displayed in the page in which both the JS files exist. So I am not sure how jQuery can be of use here. So I was expecting to not include the jQuery library to avoid bloating the page and instead, use it on custom_script.php page as needed. I am stuck with this part as I never dealt with it before. Any help?

Comment: I dont see a JS file. I see a PHP file that generates some HTML, that you are requesting as JS (which is plain wrong as another user already states). Plus: this "JS-file" cannot be copied to other user as when they execute (if they are even able to) the php they will get wrong or just no results, as they don't have your database.

Comment: @ohcibi I have listed only the first JS file as I do not know what to put in the 2nd JS file. Hence I left it out. Actually users can request the JS file from their account. Whenever a user makes a request, the same JS file with a different unique_id is created and given to the user. The user can now use these JS files in the websites of their choice. So the unique_id is basically pulling out the data related to their account and displaying in test.html page. Yes, the don't have my database and that's the point. I have a central DB and that will act as server. Makes sense now?

Comment: @Devner You have _not_ posted a JS file. You have posted a PHP file that (presumably) generates some JS. The PHP file you posted actually generates HTML. But the presumption comes by seeing that you have requested it as javascript. So this is the point that is totally unclear. Who runs this php script? Where should the output go? If the stuff that the php(!) file you pasted is the stuff that you actually want your users to download than you should rephrase your question as this file has nothing to do with JS. Maybe you should try to just describe your problem and not how you tried to solve it.

Comment: @ohcibi Sorry if its unclear. I will try to explain again. The first JS file (Yes, its not an actual JS file, rather its a PHP file but accessed through a JS file) is pasted by the user in HIS website. So let's say you are a user. You register on "MY website" www.myserver.com and create an account & add your personal info. You want this info to be shown to YOUR website users. So you request code and the JS files will be given to you. You will paste these files in your website and your personal info will be shown to your users. Contd...

Comment: @Devner please read what I and other people alread wrote: It is NOT a JS file. You are requesting it as JS but thats wrong as it is no JS. (Your browser will trivially throw an error at the first occurance of a `<` because thats not valid JS-syntax). You can't explain this right, if you hold on these wrong assumptions.

Comment: @ohcibi ..Contd First JS file is used to send your unique ID to my server & 2nd JS file is intended to receive the response from MY PHP script with the HTML data and will be responsible for the display of the data. You (the user) is doing this as you dont want to maintain this info yourself. Rather my server, my domain and my database will be a central repository to hold this data together. Your friends can join and add this data into MY database and simply use the 2 JS files to show the info on YOUR websites. So this eliminates all need & technical expertise on your end to maintain DB.Got it?

Comment: I guess I got it. Will try to make an answer

Comment: In fact the right answer was already given and I dont want to double post. See my comment in the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28832/discussion-between-ohcibi-and-devner)

Comment: The only thing worse than using the dangerous and deprecated `mysql_query` interface is using it inside a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery documentation actually gives an example almost identical to your problem:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

This will get an html page and insert it under an html element with class 'result'.

You should be able to replace your php script url and specify where the output should be displayed.

If youre worried about conflicts with other jQuery instances, have a read of this:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

If you want to write your own AJAX handler check out this page : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Essentially you will do something like this (taken from the link):

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
};

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "yourFile.txt", true);
oReq.send();
```

I think its worth doing if you've never had to do it before, but you will open yourself up to lots of potential problems that have been solved for you.

Ideally if I were doing this I would return json from the handler and allow the user to decide how to display it, but thats your call.

Comment: User has neither the idea, nor the choice to customize the data display. It's just a plug-and-play solution for them. These files are meant to show information related to their account. Users can simply include these JS files in the pages where they want to display their info and that's it. I am going to take a look at the link you posted and I will get back to you on that. Meanwhile, if you come across any other ideas to solve the issue, please feel free to share. Thanks.

Comment: You have mistaken your PHP script as a JS file as I already said. You only need one javascript that does exactly what is shown in this answer (replace `ajax/test.html` with the url to your php script). The script would then add the data into a container with a class of `.result` you could easily tweak that by appending to the body or do something else. YES your users will need jquery for this. But if it stays that simple you could try to do the XHTTPRequest and the selection of the target element in plain JS (which you could look up in the jquery source; but believe me: almost nobody does it)

Comment: @ohcibi Please check my Edit 1. Perhaps that will clear up my motives even better.

Comment: @Devner as long as you dont understand, that your browser will never parse your HTML that is generated by your PHP file as JavaScript nor will it use it as HTML if you request it as JavaScript, it will be hard to explain what your error is 8-)). Oh and btw. GA is doing it similar as in this answer (although not with jquery 8-)). There is ONE script that queries a SERVICE (and not "another javascript" file).

Comment: @ohcibi As you may have understood, I am very novice in this area and this is first time I am dealing with it, so your patience is appreciated. I can't force the users to include jQuery file. Simple reason is that if they are already using an older version of jQuery & I force them to include a newer version, their current functionality will break. So I think the best way to solve this is to do it just like Google Analytics does it. But I don't have a clue as to how they do it. So I will try to search some more. Meanwhile, if you have any suggestions/ideas, they are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom It does not look like its possible to achieve this without using jQuery. And forcing users to include jQuery does not sound like a good idea as that might break any existing functionality. So is there possibly any way this could be done? I am open to new solutions. Thanks.

Comment: @devner come back to that chat session if you like

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28908/discussion-between-devner-and-ohcibi)

Comment: @ohcibi Hi, I am in chat now.

Comment: Updated with a link that might help.

Comment: @TomElmore Going to check it. Thanks for updating.